The colorframed package adds extra vertical space at the end when inside another environment
The colorframed package (and its predecessor framed) adds extra vertical space when inside another environment.
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{colorframed}
 \colorlet{shadecolor}{lightgray}

\begin{document}

This is text before quotation, but it must be longer than one line for comparison purposes.
\begin{snugshade*}
Purely fictional thinking leads to testing text inside shaded text environments.
\end{snugshade*}
This is text between quotation, but it must be longer than one line for comparison purposes.
\begin{quotation}\begin{snugshade*}
Purely fictional thinking leads to testing text inside shaded text environments.
\end{snugshade*}\end{quotation}
This is text after quotations, but it must be longer than one line for comparison purposes.

\end{document}

Any way to fix this?

Do you use the quotation environment just to change the text width or are there other reasons as well?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz To change the text margins (to the quotation environment margins) only.

In this case something like  \begin{center}\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth} \begin{snugshade*} Purely fictional thinking leads to testing text inside shaded text environments. \end{snugshade*}\end{minipage}\end{center} seems easier

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I want to avoid minipage as it does not break across pages.  (That is why I am using the colorframed environment in the first place).

If you want page breaks, I would use the tcolorbox package. There you can do all at once. Add a coloured background, change the margins, allow page breaks ...

I looked into colorframed code for the snugshade* environment and hacked into it to create a quotedsnugshade* environment admitting an optional parameter to control the amount of indenting.
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{colorframed}
 \colorlet{shadecolor}{lightgray}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{quotedsnugshade*}[1][2em]{%
  \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin 
  \colorframedcolorbox{shadecolor}{##1}%
      \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
  \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
\advance\hsize-2\dimexpr#1\relax    %%% ADDED 
\@totalleftmargin\dimexpr#1\relax   %%% ADDED
\linewidth\hsize
    \advance\labelsep\fboxsep
    \@setminipage}%
 }{\par\unskip\@minipagefalse\endMakeFramed}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


This is text before quotations, but it must be longer than one line for comparison purposes.
\begin{quotedsnugshade*}
Purely fictional thinking leads to testing text inside shaded text environments.
\end{quotedsnugshade*}
This is text after quotations, but it must be longer than one line for comparison purposes.
\begin{quotation}
  Purely fictional thinking leads to testing text inside quotation environment.
\end{quotation}
This is text after quotations, but it must be longer than one line for comparison purposes.
\begin{quotedsnugshade*}[2cm]
Purely fictional thinking leads to testing text inside shaded text environments.
\end{quotedsnugshade*}
\noindent\rule{2cm}{1pt}\dotfill margins are 2cm each\dotfill\rule{2cm}{1pt}

\end{document}

Note that this is not tested with contents of shaded thing being itself a list.


With the tcolorbox package you can have a coloured background, page breaks and adjusted margins all at once (the space above and below can be adjusted if needed):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{quack}[1][]{enhanced,breakable,frame hidden,colback=lightgray,sharp corners,size=small,left skip=1cm,right skip=1cm,#1}

\begin{document}

This is text between quotation, but it must be longer than one line for comparison purposes.
\begin{quack}
Purely fictional thinking leads to testing text inside shaded text environments.
\end{quack}
This is text after quotations, but it must be longer than one line for comparison purposes.

\end{document}


